Get id from Second Table Database Relation in Multiple Db Laravel
HI I am using Multiple Database both have Same name of Table Name Employees in DB one
employees




db1
DB2




Employees
Employees



I get Some of information from DB2 to DB1  NOW D2 Contain already Employee information



db.employees
db2.employees




id
id


name , Email
name Email



now the issue i am facing I wanna use id of db2.employee so i don't Generate  New id Every time
use App\Models\EmployeApi // is where is Second Database is connected 

PHP:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Employee;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Schedule;
use App\Http\Requests\EmployeeRec;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;
use App\Models\EmployeApi as EmployeApi;  // area where IS Secound db is used // imran NIAZ

class EmployeeController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        return view('admin.employee')->with(['employees'=> Employee::all(), 'schedules'=>Schedule::all()]);
    }

    public function store(EmployeeRec $request)
    {
        $request->validated();

        $employee = new Employee;
        // $employee->id = EmployeApi::getId();
        $employee->name = $request->name;
        $employee->position = $request->position;
        $employee->email = $request->email;
        $employee->pin_code = bcrypt($request->pin_code);
        $employee->save();

        if($request->schedule){

            $schedule = Schedule::whereSlug($request->schedule)->first();

            $employee->schedules()->attach($schedule);
        }

        // $role = Role::whereSlug('emp')->first();

        // $employee->roles()->attach($role);

        flash()->success('Success','Employee Record has been created successfully !');

        return redirect()->route('employees.index')->with('success');
    }


    public function update(EmployeeRec $request, Employee $employee)
    {
        $request->validated();

        $employee->name = $request->name;
        $employee->position = $request->position;
        $employee->email = $request->email;
        $employee->pin_code = bcrypt($request->pin_code);
        $employee->save();

        if ($request->schedule) {

            $employee->schedules()->detach();

            $schedule = Schedule::whereSlug($request->schedule)->first();

            $employee->schedules()->attach($schedule);
        }

        flash()->success('Success','Employee Record has been Updated successfully !');

        return redirect()->route('employees.index')->with('success');
    }


    public function destroy(Employee $employee)
    {
        $employee->delete();

        // Remove employee from device
        // Add code here to remove employee from device

        flash()->success('Success','Employee Record has been Deleted successfully !');
        return redirect()->route('employees.index')->with('success');
    }
}

Model
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class EmployeApi extends Model
{
    // Specify the connection name defined in config/database.php
    protected $connection = 'second_db';
    // Specify the table associated with the model
    protected $table = 'employees';
}


what do you expect from this EmployeApi::getId() ? it should have some conditions to search for this employee to return with it if exists

its mean is simple that if the employee exist IN Second data base > employee and get that and save in  first db >employee

If i understand you correctly, you could try something like this
by searching with the email on the second database
$reference = EmployeApi::where('email', $request->email)->first();

$employee = new Employee;
if($reference) {
   $employee->id = $reference->id;
}

$employee->name = $request->name;
$employee->position = $request->position;
$employee->email = $request->email;
$employee->pin_code = bcrypt($request->pin_code);
$employee->save();

but i don't recommend this approach there is a better way, by adding a new column on the employee table from the first DB called reference_id and then the the value on it rather than overwriting the primary key
Here is the enhanced code
$reference = EmployeApi::where('email', $request->email)->first();

$employee = new Employee;
if($reference) {
   $employee->reference_id = $reference->id;
}

$employee->name = $request->name;
$employee->position = $request->position;
$employee->email = $request->email;
$employee->pin_code = bcrypt($request->pin_code);
$employee->save();

